# using select where statement using php variables

Tags: php, mysqli

this is a code block to load data from database into a table structure in the page. the select statement is used to load data. but in the page it display the following error message [mysqli error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7inA.png)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h3>Company Overview </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Overview</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Contact_Number</th>    
                    <th>Created By</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php include('sessions.php');
                $login_session;
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM company_overview where created_by LIKE "' . $login_session . '" '; ?>
                <?php $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); ?>
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    ?>
                    <?php echo '<tr>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<td>' . $row['company_name'] . '</td>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<td>' . $row['company_overview'] . '</td>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<td>' . $row['address'] . '</td>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<td>' . $row['contact_no'] . '</td>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<td>' . $row['created_by'] . '</td>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<td width=250>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update_p.php">Update</a>'; ?>
                    <?php echo ' '; ?>
                    <?php echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_promotion.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '</td>'; ?>
                    <?php echo '</tr>'; ?>
                    <?php include('o_sessions.php'); ?>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php //mysqli_close($conn); ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: add appropriate column name after WHERE clause in your query and add % in like

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong in WHERE clause part. Always use `mysqli_error()` with any call to DB in order to check if there any errors. And where you are assiging something to `$login_session` before DB call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add appropriate column name after WHERE statement and add % in like:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM company_overview where column_name LIKE "%'.$login_session.'%" ';
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use `mysqli_num_rows()` to check your query contain result or not.
2. Use `column name` with `WHERE` and use %..% with LIKE.
3. Your code contains extra open close `<?php ?>` please correct it.

Please check comments and change your code. I have added mysqli_num_rows() and prevent your code from error. Other things you can do it by yourself.

```
<?php 
    include('sessions.php'); 
    $login_session; 
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM company_overview where id LIKE "%'.$login_session.'%" ';
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
         <?php   echo '<tr>';?>
         <?php   echo '<td>'. $row['company_name'] . '</td>';?>
         <?php   echo '<td>'. $row['company_overview'] . '</td>';?>
         <?php   echo '<td>'. $row['address'] . '</td>';?>
     <?php   echo '<td>'. $row['contact_no'] . '</td>';?>
     <?php   echo '<td>'. $row['created_by'] . '</td>';?>
         <?php   echo '<td width=250>';?>
         <?php echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update_p.php">Update</a>';?>
         <?php   echo ' ';?>
         <?php   echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="delete_promotion.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';?>
         <?php   echo '</td>';?>
         <?php   echo '</tr>';?>
<?php include('o_sessions.php');?>
    <?php   } }?>
<?php    //mysqli_close($conn);?>
</tbody>
```